# Riemann Integration and measure zero

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing, riemann-integration

Show that if $A$ has measure zero in $R^n$, the sets $\overline{A}$ and $\mbox{Bd}(A)$ need not have measure zero.

Attempt at a solution: 
I know we could use a counter example but I'm trying to practice proof writing and I was wondering if someone could tell me if my proof works and how I could improve upon it.

Let $a_i \in A \setminus \mbox{Bd}(A)$  and $a_i{'}$ $\in \mbox{Bd}(A)$
If $A$ has measure zero we can cover $A$ with rectangles $Q_1, Q_2, \ldots $ such that 
$\sum_{i=1}^\infty v(Q_i) < \epsilon$. 
Let $\mbox{Bd}(A) = B_(a',\epsilon)$. Then adjoin to $Q_i$ the set $Q$ that covers $\mbox{Bd}(A)$. We know from construction of $\mbox{Bd}(A)$ that $V(Q) \ge \epsilon$. Then the total volume of $Q_i + Q$ $\ge \epsilon $ and this implies that $\mbox{Bd}(A)$ and $\overline{A}$ are not necessarily of measure zero.

Comment: Hint: find a countable dense subset

Comment: $A\setminus Bd(A)$ may be empty. As noted in the previous comment you may take $A$ to be a countable dense set, e.g. the rationals. Then $A$ has measure zero (in the reals), but $Bd(A)=\overline A$ is the real line.

Comment: Finding a counter-example, and properly proving that your counter example works and conveying that, would still qualify as working on proof writing.

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:riemann-integration]?

Comment: How about : Let A be the rationals in the unit interval. It has measure zero, but its closure and its boundary are the entire unit interval, which has measure 1.